# How To Fix 404 Errors On An Entire Site?

Tags: htaccess, seo, shopify

I have a PPC l client who recently re-designed their e-commerce site. The only problem is that every single old link that they had before is now a 404 error. They had a fairly healthy organic ranking before as many of their site links showed up on the 1st page for a particular keyword - now that url shows up as a 404. They also have brand NEW links on top of that which are what I'm using for their ads.

I understand that these kind of things happen when old links aren't re-directed to the new site links and when the site isn't re-submitted for re-indexing.

My simple solution would be to do 301 redirects and then submit the site for indexing on GSC.

However while mining their site on Google, I've additionally discovered that their entire site is riddled with over 500+ urls of 404 errors - I'm assuming from years and years of doing the above.

I've read that doing bulk 301 redirects isn't a good idea, and bearing in mind that I'm not a dev specialist, what would be the best and simplest solution for this issue? Doing 410s instead?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What is the current e-commerce platform and what was the old one, please clarify? If the current one is Shopify there is no `.htaccess` file there, it's a closed platform and you don't have access to the back-end code. But there is an URL redirect feature, where you can redirect old URLS to new ones.

Comment: Where did you hear that bulk redirects are bad?   Can you share a source?   Bulk redirecting many URLs to one destination (like redirecting all 404s to the home page) would be bad, but individually redirecting each URL to its new URL would be SEO friendly, even if there are a ton of them.

Comment: Sitemaps have very little to do with it.   An XML sitemap can get Googlebot to crawl all the new URLs, but Google doesn't use XML sitemaps as a strong signal for whether or not to index a URL.  Nor to sitemaps help rankings.   See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)